# Microphone not working on 3d sound card

Tags: audio

I am trying to connect an old phone receiver to a raspberry pi. the receiver has two wires for the speaker and two for the microphone. Following a tutorial online I solder the connection of each to the tip and ring connectors of 3.5mm jacks. this worked fine on an Olympus recorder - I can record from the microphone and listen from the speaker. But when connecting the receiver to the Raspberry Pi with a 3d sound card only the speaker works but I cannot hear anything through the mic.

I also tried soldering the wires differently - one to the sleeve and one to the tip or the ring with no result. On a windows computer I also don't hear anything.

On an old lap top the had the right connections I managed to hear the mic when I set the mic boost to +10db, but this setting is not available for the card.

Am I doing some thing wrong, or do i need a different type of sound card - and if so - what?

I am usind a card like this [image: 3d sound cartd]

Comment: More info needed. We don't know what you bought, what mics it supports and how you connected things, draw some schematics. Does the sound card work with another headset properly or not?

Comment: I added a picture of the card. I am new to this site - what kind of schematics would you need?

Comment: I'd try connecting something like a mp3 player to the "microphone" input first. It's not uncommon for "microphone" inputs on cheap usb devices to be a glorified line-in with no microphone bias voltage.

Comment: You are right. the mp3 gave normal sound. SDo i need a different card or can i build a simple circuit or some thing?

Comment: You'd need a "microphone bias circuit". In it simplest form a DC power supply, some resistors to set the bias voltage and a capacitor to AC couple the audio out. Possibly a preamplifier aswell if the sound card input is not sensitive enough.

Comment: I tested the card and saw 2.8v between the sleeve and the ring as well as between the sleeve and the tip, this is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my problem was polarity - I didn't know the mic has polarity. I flipped the wires and it worked.